# Inconsistent paging per page

Tags: paging

I have created a custom module whishow data from table.I have used following code:

```
$query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->extend('TableSort');
$query
->fields('u', array('fields'))
->fields('n', array('fields'))
->limit(50)
->orderByHeader($header)
->setCountQuery($count_query);
```

It show the pagination correctly (50 per page) when there is less data.But when no. of rows exceeds 1 lakhs it show inconsistent rows per page.

Comment: how is the data being displayed? through your own module? through views? through core search? through a 3rd party search module? or something else...

Comment: I am displaying it with my ow module.Actually i come to know the problem.Its because tableselect index.My index value of tableselect is not unique so its not showing the similar data.